# Sort data frame by numbers

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame with about 40 columns 2000 rows. One of them has numbers and letters like this :

```
CLN

5T
14S
1A
12N
```

At first I used the `melt` in order to get a long structure of my data. I want to plot my data with the CLN at the yaxis but with the order of numbers like : 1A,5T,12N,14S. I know that I have to use the `sort` but how can I do this for my numbers and letters? (I am sorry but my df is huge and I cannot provide a productive example).

Comment: Your post says `how can I do this for my numbers only and not the letters?`  Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes I am sorry. I want to do the sorting based on the numbers but I don't want to remove the letters because for my plot I want the order to be like: 1A,1T,1N,1S...3A,3T,3N,3S. It is a huge df so there are many combinations between letters and numbers  and I need the sorting for both but first based on numbers.

Comment: Okay, my solution is not removing any letters, but it order based on the numbers leaving the letters untouched

Comment: Yes and it works for the numbers(thank you) but still I have to do this for the letters too..

Comment: Okay, then your post is misleading i.e. `how can I do this for my numbers only and not the letters?`

Comment: Oh boy, here come the head games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `mixedsort` from `gtools`:

```
vec <- c("5T", "14S", "1A", "12N")

gtools::mixedsort(vec)
# [1] "1A"  "5T"  "12N" "14S"
```

Comment: As I said my df is huge so the creation of a vector with all the combinations is pretty tough.

Comment: @g.f.l It works on columns too.

Comment: @mtoto you are right,I tried it and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If we need to `sort` by numbers, one way is to remove the non-numeric part using `sub`, convert to `numeric` and `order` the column.  The OP's post says

> how can I do this for my numbers only and not the letters?

```
v1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", df1$CLN))
df1$CLN <- df1$CLN[order(v1)]
df1$CLN
#[1] "1A"  "5T"  "12N" "14S"
```

If we need to do this for both letters and numbers

```
v2 <- sub("\\d+", "", df1$CLN)
df1$CLN <- df1$CLN[order(v1, v2)]
```

Then, we change it to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements of 'CLN' for using that order in the `plot`.

```
df1$CLN <- factor(df1$CLN, levels = unique(df1$CLN))
```

NOTE: These are `base R` options and no packages used.

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(CLN = c("5T", "14S", "1A", "12N"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```