# Mixedorder data frame in R

Tags: r, sorting, mixed

I have a data frame which looks like this :

```
a = c("1A","10A","11A","2B","2C","22C","3A","3B")
b= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
ab = data.frame(a,b)
```

and I want to sort it according to the column `a`. I tried the mixed order

```
library(gtools)
ab[mixedorder(ab$a),]
```

but I don' t get the result I want (1A,2B,2C,3A,3B..). 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to convert to `character` class (as the 'a' column is `factor` based on the default option in `data.frame` call i.e. `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`)

```
ab[mixedorder(as.character(ab$a)),]
#    a b
#1  1A 1
#4  2B 4
#5  2C 5
#7  3A 7
#8  3B 8
#2 10A 2
#3 11A 3
#6 22C 6
```

Additional options are also explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056929/sort-data-frame-by-numbers/39056957#39056957)

Answer (score 4):

I'd just split the column. If you want numeric order for the numbers part of the ID, you should probably have these numbers as a numeric column anyway.

```
ab$a1 <- as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]+]", "", ab$a))
ab$a2 <- gsub("\\d+", "", ab$a)

ab[order(ab$a1, ab$a2),]
#    a b a1 a2
#1  1A 1  1  A
#4  2B 4  2  B
#5  2C 5  2  C
#7  3A 7  3  A
#8  3B 8  3  B
#2 10A 2 10  A
#3 11A 3 11  A
#6 22C 6 22  C
```

Comment: Also maybe `setDT(ab)[do.call(order, tstrsplit(ab$a, "(?=\\D)", perl = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE))]`